# Get-AzureAutomationAccount returns empty collection

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I can't seem to access anything with the Azure Automation `cmdlets` from an azure runbook.  Below I successfully get all the VMs in my subscription but a call to `Get-AzureAutomationAccount` returns an empty collection (where I do have 2 automation accounts).  Any other calls I can make using the automation `cmdlets` either return empty or not found exceptions.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
workflow Get-AzureVMTutorial
{
#The name of the Automation Credential Asset this runbook will use to authenticate to Azure.
$CredentialAssetName = 'AaronCred'

#Get the credential with the above name from the Automation Asset store
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $CredentialAssetName
if(!$Cred) {
    Throw "Could not find an Automation Credential Asset named '${CredentialAssetName}'. Make sure you have created one in this Automation Account."
}

#Connect to your Azure Account
$Account = Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred
if(!$Account) {
    Throw "Could not authenticate to Azure using the credential asset '${CredentialAssetName}'. Make sure the user name and password are correct."
}

#TODO (optional): pick the right subscription to use. Without this line, the default subscription for your Azure Account will be used.
#Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "TODO: your Azure subscription name here"

#Get all the VMs you have in your Azure subscription
$VMs = Get-AzureVM

#Print out up to 10 of those VMs
if(!$VMs) {
    Write-Output "No VMs were found in your subscription."
} else {
    Write-Output $VMs[0..9]
}

# PROBLEM - No accounts are returned even though I have 2
$automationAccounts = Get-AzureAutomationAccount

#Print out up to 10 of those automation accounts
if(!$automationAccounts) {
    Write-Output "No automation accounts were found in your subscription."
} else {
    Write-Output $VMs[0..9]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create the Automation accounts through ARM / the new (formerly preview) Azure portal (portal.azure.com) or through RDFE / ASM / the old Azure portal (manage.windowsazure.com)? If the former, the Automation accounts will not be accessible through RDFE / ASM / the old Azure portal, including via the `Get-AzureAutomationAccount` cmdlet. From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-configuring/#automation-accounts:

> Automation accounts, and the resources they contain, that are created with the Azure preview portal cannot be accessed in the Azure portal. If you want to manage these accounts or their resources with Windows PowerShell, you must use the Azure Resource Manager modules.
>
> Automation accounts created with the Azure portal can be managed by either portal and either set of cmdlets. Once the account is created, it makes no difference how you create and manage resources within the account. If you are planning to continue to use the Azure portal, then you should use it instead of the Azure preview portal to create any Automation accounts.

If this is indeed the cause of the issue, the solution is to use the ARM cmdlets, rather than the RDFE/ASM cmdlets, to access your Automation accounts and anything within them. Ex:

`Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Cred
Get-AzureRmAutomationAccount
Get-AzureRmAutomationRunbook`

Comment: I have been exclusively using portal.azure.com, in fact the automation account was created just for testing this problem yesterday through portal.azure.com.

Comment: OK, then you need to use the cmdlets that correspond to that portal: Add-AzureRmAccount, Get-AzureRmAutomationAccount, Get-AzureRmAutomationRunbook, etc, as this answer says. Get-AzureAutomationAccount is a cmdlet that corresponds to the old portal.

Comment: This is the correct answer then.  Thank you very much Joe.  Reading the link you sent I found I need to use the Azure Resources Manager Cmdlets (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt244122.aspx) when I create my Azure automation account through portal.azure.com.  

Unfortunately their main page right now at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/automation/ (Automate->Automation Cmdlets) points to the old documentation, which is what I used mistakenly.